# I can't make a boolean on Vertices?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Maybe there is some way? Unexpectedly, I could not find the answer to the question in Google

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean operators use Faces to determine what is intersecting and what isn't. Vertices can't intersect with a mesh, since they are technically volumeless

Comment: GODDAMN! It doesn't look hard to implement

Comment: What is your intended end result? Are you wanting to cut a tube-shaped hole out of the cube? If so, you can just add a Skin modifer to the vertices, apply it, and then the Boolean will work

Comment: Round off the ends of the road if you are interested, I had to act destructively with my hands 
https://imgur.com/a/L0qgYDQ